# Why no nesting in CSS?

Tags: css

Seems like it would be a nice way to have css structured.  Are there cases that would make this impossible?

I am thinking of something like the following:

```
table#myTable{
    thead{
        color:red;
    }
    tbody{
        color:blue;
        td.title{
            background-color: green;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: have a look at http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 2):

I can't answer *why* CSS doesn't have this feature.  There are a few systems such as LESS (http://lesscss.org/) that allows you to write structures like this, and then 'compile' them down to regular CSS.

*Nested example in LESS: (from that link)*

Nested Rules
Rather than constructing long selector names to specify inheritance, in Less you can simply nest selectors inside other selectors. This makes inheritance clear and style sheets shorter.

```
#header {
  color: red;
  a {
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: .. as the other posters have said, SASS is another alternative. I don't use them myself so couldn't tell you which is better, though less looks more like 'CSS+' than SASS's different syntax.

Comment: How about a filter that can do compilation on server side?  I guess you could run the conversion in the deployment process though.

Comment: @Eric Winter: If you're using Ruby, LESS can be used from inside your script. Converting during deployment sounds more reasonable though - as always, code does exactly what you told it, which may not be what you actually wanted ;)

Answer (score 0):

Because at the time of the spec writing no one probably thought of the idea, or not enough people thought it would be useful.

You can use SASS, though: http://sass-lang.com/

Example syntax:

```
table.hl
  margin: 2em 0
  td.ln
    text-align: right

li
  font:
    family: serif
    weight: bold
    size: 1.2em
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be nice, but that's the way CSS is designed and organized doesn't support that.

However, there are CSS preprocessors which allow you to code this way, and then process it into real, valid CSS - such as [LessCSS](http://lesscss.org/).

Answer (score 0):

You may still indent your selectors according to your document structure:

```
body {
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: #666;
}

    #Header {
        /* stuff */
    }

        #Header ul {
            /* stuff */
        }

            #Header il {
                /* stuff */
            }

    #Content {
        /* stuff */
    }
```

Other than the sporadic background-image: url(''); properties generally don't run very long, and during development this might help you keep organized. I personally prefer unindented CSS because I often let Textmate reformat my stylesheets.

Comment: That is a good point.  I'll see what the team thinks.